# Индивидуальное общение с участником SO

Tags: поддержка

Есть ли на Stack Overflow способ написать сообщение произвольному участнику?

Т.е. не комментарий с обращением `@Name` в каком-то вопросе, а не относящееся к какому-либо вопросу сообщение? Я пользовался общением в чате, но только в ситуациях, когда туда переносилось затянувшееся общение в комментариях к некоторому вопросу в ленте.

Comment: Вы можете создавать чат самостоятельно и приглашать собеседника в него.

Comment: @vp_arth, ткните мордой дурака , как это сделать самому? Система предлагает чат после десятка сообщений или модераторы переносят обсуждение в чат. А как самому создать чат и позвать туда участника до сих пор не понимаю, порой не охота флудить в обсуждении, выясняя подробности.

Comment: @DaemonHK: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms

Comment: @jfs читал, но не увидел вожделенной ссылки тогда (читал между строк как обычно), теперь понятно как создавать и приглашать пользователей, спасибо

Comment: эксперимент показал, что приглашения в чат работают, хотя интерфейс не слишком прямолинейный (может это и хорошо, что есть [небольшое] трение, чтобы других людей дёргать).